# saving data as a file in mac osx

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Basically, i want to save NSData as a file using NSSaver. what do i add into my if statement to save it/what corrections should i make to this method?

```
 - (IBAction)saveAs:(id)sender{

NSMutableArray *storage = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[arrayController arrangedObjects] count]];
for (int i = 0; i < [[arrayController arrangedObjects] count]; i++) {
    Stores *object = [[arrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:object.Website, @"website",object.Street_Address, @"streetAddress", object.City_Address, @"cityAddress", object.Name, @"storeName", object.Latitude, @"latidude", object.Longitude, @"longitude", object.Phone_Number, @"phoneNumber", nil];
[storage addObject:dict];
}
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveDataWithRootObject:storage];
NSSavePanel *saver = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
saver.requiredFileType = @"yogurtstorelocations";
[saver runModal];
if ([saver runModal] == NSOKButton){


    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error handling code omitted.

```
[data writeToURL:[saver URL] atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I'm not actually at a Mac right now so the code I posted is a hair above psuedo-code. But it should compile and run. What was your error?

Comment: Oh wait a second, I just noticed you are running your NSSavePanel twice. Take out the first [saver runModal], the line right above the if block.

Comment: i figured it out. the method was `[data writeToURL:[saver URL] atomically:YES];`. thanks for the help~